# SQL: Error: near "(": syntax error | primary key problem

Tags: sql, database, syntax-error, primary-key, database-table

The professor asked us to create two tables and alter them.

```
create table student
(
    name varchar(25) not null,
    std_num int(12),
    std_num(primary)
);
```

When I click "Run SQL", it shows the following message:

> `Error: near "(": syntax error`

without additional details.

I'm using Programiz online SQL editor.

I tried to delete the following code:

```
std_num int(12),
std_num(primary)
```

Then it created the table.

Am I writing a primary key in the table in an incorrect way?

What is the meaning of the message `Error: near "(": syntax error`?

How do I fix the error?

If my method was wrong, how do I correctly include a primary key in a table?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Maybe change this 

std_num int(12),
std_num(primary)

to std_num int(12) primary key

Comment: Click on `Edit tags`

Comment: Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't provide the database you are using, I just do a quick guess it should be one of them: `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle` or `SQLite`

For all above database's type, the syntax `std_num(primary)` for defining a primary key, as in your code, is not a standard SQL syntax.

There are two ways to define Primary Key:

1. Inline with Column Definition: The PRIMARY KEY keyword is placed directly in the column definition. This is common when the table has a single-column primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    std_num INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

2. Separate Constraint Definition: The PRIMARY KEY keyword is used after all column definitions, especially useful for composite keys (primary keys consisting of multiple columns).

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    std_num INT,
    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (std_num)
);
```

Additionally, The `int(12)` syntax in MySQL does not mean the integer will have 12 digits. Instead, it specifies the display width, which is often a point of confusion. For a primary key, just `int` is typically sufficient unless you have a specific requirement for the display width.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you are using MySQL or MariaDB which usually does not indicates the nature of the error unlike other RDBMSs which provide details.
You therefore commit 3 syntax errors:

- The expression must be PRIMARY KEY
- the expression must appear at the head of the definition of a table object (column or constraint)
- and the key words PRIMARY KEY must not appear in parentheses
- and the columns that compound the PRIMARY KEY is a list and must appear in parentheses...

This is a lot of mistakes and I advise you to start by learning the SQL language before starting to write queries....

The right code is :

```
create table student
(
    name varchar(25) not null,
    std_num int(12),
    PRIMARY KEY (std_num)
);
```